# Elastic Search sub string match

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search

I have elastic search node containing index like this :

```
"_index" : "barivara",
       "_type" : "_doc",
       "_id" : "3",
       "_score" : 1.0,
       "_source" : {
         "area" : "Mirpur",
         "address" : "house:5; MIrpur",
         "description" : "home",
         "price" : 400,
         "number of members" : 5,
         "building amenities" : "5",
         "number of bed" : 7,
         "number of bath" : 2,
         "rentaltype" : "flat",
         "fttext" : "Mirpur 7 bedroom 2 bathroom flat 10 members"
       }
     }
```

I added the text field for full text search, but when I am searching "3 bedroom Mirpur"

The index containing 7 bedroom also appears.

Heres my query/

```
GET /barivara/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": { 
          "fttext": {
            "query":                "bedroom:3 Mirpur",
            "minimum_should_match": "100%"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

can someone help me? I am a noob in elastic search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give more info on what type of **analyser** you have configured, and what is the **schema of your document**, assuming they are standard, here is my take.

1. The query is converted to tokens based on **analyzer**
2. Then based on internal **inverted index,** it finds out which all documents match them
3. Then based on **relevance score,** order them and return the results.

So, in your case, input "bedroom:3 Mirpur" is broken down in 3 words "bedroom", "3" and "Mirpur" and is search against all the documents inside field "fttext" in the index, and return the results.

So in you case, **"7 bedroom"** documents will also appear as **2 out of 3 terms** are matched for those document but such document will be placed below the **"3 bedroom"** documents

**NOTE** : Assuming fttext is type of "**text**" and not "**keyword**" in your schema. Keyword as not analyzed during indexing and are stored as "whole word(s)". So "contains" does not work on them, exact search do.